# Form in one page button on other page how to perform this action?

Tags: forms

I need to submit form for updating cart in magento so as to do that I have a button Update cart but the button should be in other page as per the PSD document now is that possible if I click button on this page and the action should be done which is in other page.

Please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops I got the answer for this.
just followed this process.

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="submitForms()" />


submitForms = function(){
    document.forms["form1"].submit();
    document.forms["form2"].submit();
}
```